# Force a change to a program's key bindings

Tags: macos, keyboard, system-settings

Is it possible to force a change to a program's keybindings?  E.g., instead of an menu action being invoked by Cmd-J it's Cmd-K?

The reason I ask is that Cmd-Q in Firefox drives me nuts.  I occasionally hit it instead of Cmd-W (to close a tab) & I have to wait for my entire instance of Firefox to stop & then restart.  I'd love to bind "Quit" to something ridiculous (or remove it all together).

My hope is this is in a resource file that's easily hacked?

Comment: I think this link will help you http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/808/find-and-change-system-shortcut

Comment: Hmmm.. see me comment below, but that doesn't seem to work in my case.  Does Cmd-Q or Quit have special properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No resource file hacking necessary; it's all built in to the GUI. And not only that, but Apple's even documented it:

- [Using global keyboard shortcuts](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8557.html)
- [Creating keyboard shortcuts for applications](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8564.html)

(the above assumes you're on OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard, but everyone with a supported system should be by now.)

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know you could do that.  However, in the case of quitting Firefox it doesn't seem to work.  I've mapped to something crazy (Cmd-Opt-Shift-P) to Quit, and I'm mapped Cmd-Q to Find.  It shows up correctly in the menu, however, Cmd-Q still quits Firefox.