# Is reassigning or disabling short-key possible?

Tags: keyboard

The finder has the Command-H assigned to 'hide finder'. Can I reassign the key to something else? Or can I disable the Command-H short key to hide finder only through menu?

Comment: Maybe this topic help you http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/808/find-and-change-system-shortcut

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.

Open `System Preferences`, Keyboard. Click the Keyboard Shortcuts tab at the top. In the left pane, select `Application Shortcuts`. In the right pane, select Finder.app. Click the `+` at the bottom of this pane. For Menu Title, type the exact wording / spelling of the menu item in question: in this case **Hide Finder**. For Keyboard Shortcut, pick another keystroke combination to hide the finder (I use function key F1). Voila. Now go to Finder and look at the Finder menu; beside Hide Finder should be F1 (or whatever you chose).

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign a shortcut to something like the NUL control character by editing the property list directly.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder NSUserKeyEquivalents '{"Hide Finder"="\0";}'
```

If a shortcut was assigned to nil, it would be shown as N in System Preferences and pressing L would trigger it in some applications like Audacity.