# OS X: disable CMD-H or "Hide App" command?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I *never* (intentionally) hide an app with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>, which *could* be rebound for *each* app ([e.g. Finder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4484/is-reassigning-or-disabling-short-key-possible)), but this is obviously the wrong approach. So, **(how) can you disable <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> for application-hiding *in one fell swoop*?**
[image]

Comment: Man, I wish there was a way to do what the OP wants. Is there some kind of regex-like syntax to enable remapping "System" shortcuts in ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist, as the OP hinted at in the screen shot?

The problem is that the shortcuts attach to menu item strings, but the quit and hide commands are always prefixed with the application's name :(

Comment: yeah dummest shortcut coming from windows where applications use shortcuts like this I press it by accident all the time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with Karabiner (formerly KeyRemap4MacBook):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::H, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: What if I want to use the keystroke for something else? VK_NONE means that if you hit that key, apps see nothing happening.

Comment: Who answered this, i do not see the user? But either way this was freaking genius, i have hated this for so long. And have added several of these Hide {Stupid Thing} in System Prefs. No more finally. Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 12):

If you do not want an approach for **separate applications**, but for **TOTAL disabling** of the shortcut, you can use [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) (FREE, and OPEN SOURCE :) ) and after installing it add a special [complex modification rule](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/?q=Prevent%20unintended%20command-h%20hide%20window)

The link already contains the search query, so just look for `Prevent unintended command-h hide window` and then click on `Import` and you are done!

Comment: This is an interesting application, and the fact that it is open source makes it more interesting. Thanks!

Comment: However, for some reason, I am not able to get the `Prevent unintended command-h hide window (rev 2) ` rule to work. I imported it and enabled it, but Cmd-H still hides the window.

Comment: @Rafid make sure to address any needed permissions for Karabiner. I had to update 2 or 3 different security settings before it worked for me. Karabiner lets you dismiss its dialogs as though these permissions are optional.

Comment: But this will disable `cmd+h` not only for hide window but also for some applications' `cmd+h` shortcuts.

Comment: correct @ChangdaePark, this solution as it says is for "TOTAL disabling"

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the accepted answer, this can be accomplished easily with BetterTouchTool.

Open BTT Preferences. If it isn't selected already, select **Gestures**.

Under Select Application, select **Global**.

**Add a New Shortcut**: <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> and leave the **Trigger** set to No Action.

[image: BetterTouch Tool Gestures]

Close the Preferences window, and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> should now be disabled for all applications.

The downside compared to the accepted answer is that this fix involves running an application. However since many Mac users are *already* running BTT in the background for other purposes, this fix can be done in a few seconds and might be simpler for some users.

Comment: Update: Global is now called All Apps. (Otherwise, the solution is still good after all these years!)

Answer (score 5):

[SKHD](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd) is a simple and neat hotkey daemon for macOS. It allows you to define application-specific bindings as well. You can configure a binding for your app to ignore a hotkey or even configure to send a new one instead.

For example, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> hides `Alacritty.app` by default. You would synthesize an empty keypress as below in order to ignore that keypress.

Add following configuration to your `.skhdrc`. You can list any other app from your applications directory in a new line and do whatever you like.

```
cmd - h [
  "alacritty" : skhd -k ""
  "safari" : skhd -k ""
]
```

In my case, I prefer to synthesize a different keypress: <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> and then <kbd>h</kbd> which triggers my Tmux binding (jump to left pane).

```
cmd - h [
  "alacritty" : skhd -k "ctrl - b" && skhd -k "h"
]
```

Make sure to reload SKHD after editing config file.

```
❯ skhd --reload
```