# Is it possible to send mail using Command + Enter in Mail?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mail.app

I can't think of any reason why <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Enter ↩</kbd> would not send a mail draft, instead of the current shortcut, which is <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can look at [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/808/find-and-change-system-shortcut/809#809) and apply accordingly to your case.

TL;DR version:

[image: system preferences keyboard shortcut]

Comment: Also, the keyword to assign the keyboard shortcut to is "Send"

Answer (score 4):

I tried to use the System Preferences, Keyboard Shortcuts tab to define Command+Return to send a mail.  But the effect was that Command+*Shift*+Return sends mail.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Daniel Serodio, I am using MailMate now, which kind of solves it, but it's not what you had in mind...

Comment: Just had this same issue in Big Sur, whyyyyyy?

Comment: ...and then I restarted Mail and for a laugh tried restarting Mail, which fixed it. Command+Return now works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution in [Mathias's dotfiles](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx#L493). In a Terminal window, type:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Send" "@\U21a9"
```

Then restart Mail.app