# Change send mail shortcut to tab + enter in Apple Mail

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I'm looking for a way to change the default "send" shortcut in mail to "tab + enter" (like gmail)

I've found a way to change it to `cmd + enter`with the following:

`defaults write com.apple.mail NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Send" "@\\U21a9"`

but doing something like:

`defaults write com.apple.mail NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Send" "\\u21E5\\U21a9"`

Does not work.

I've followed [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23699/is-it-possible-to-send-mail-using-command-enter-in-mail) answer, but I am unable to add the tab key in the shortcut dialog, and would prefer to do it from the command line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because tab isn't a modifier key (like command, shift, option and control), you can't use it in combination with other non-modifier keys to make a shortcut. It's simply not possible the way the OS X input systems work AFAIK.

You might be able to jury-rig something together using KeyboardMaestro or similar apps that listens for tab-return and then executes the send mail command, but I don't know how well it would work, or how closely it would match your expected behaviour.

Comment: Alas, I will have to face the pain and just re-learn that shortcut when I am using mail. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
defaults write com.apple.mail NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Send" $'@\\U21a9'
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Answer (score 0):

You could save this as [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) in KeyRemap4MacBook.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>test</name>
<identifier>private.test</identifier>
<only>MAIL</only>
<autogen>--SimultaneousKeyPresses-- KeyCode::TAB, KeyCode::RETURN, KeyCode::D, VK_SHIFT, VK_COMMAND</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```