# Edit default Finder MenuBar shortcut

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut, menu-bar

I use a custom keyboard and unfortunately, the command: < ctrl+cmd+n > in the Finder to create new folder with selection doesn't work for an obscur reason, so I would like to change it to another command, but the problem is that I cannot enter the exact name in the application keyboard shortcut because the name of the action varies (is dynamic) in function of the number of elements that are selected or because it will say : new folder with "filename".

I tried to add a custom one saying: new folder with selection (2 elements). And it worked, but only in the case that I have 2 elements. Is there a way to change the default shortcut so it will work for all files and number of files?

I tried [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/808/find-and-change-system-shortcut) But I fail when it comes to edit the .nib file.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please don''t crosspost to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://superuser.com/questions/1219433/edit-default-finder-menubar-shortcut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue: since my keyboard is remapped with UKELELE, the modifier corresponding to ctrl+cmd was not defined. After creating it, it worked fine!

[image]